# PHP show only significant (non-zero) decimals

Tags: php, numbers

In PHP (using built-in functions) I'd like to convert/format a number with decimal, so that only the non-zero decimals show. However, another requirement of mine is that if it's a number without a decimal value, I'd still like to show that zero. Examples:

```
9.000 -> 9.0
9.100 -> 9.1
9.120 -> 9.12
9.123 -> 9.123
```

`rtrim($value, "0")` almost works. The problem with rtrim is that it leaves `9.000` as `9.`. `sprintf()` seemed like a candidate, but I couldn't get it to have a variable amount of decimals. `number_format()` serves a different purpose, and those were all I could come up with...

Again, I'd like to point out that I am not looking for your homemade solutions to this, I'm looking for a way to accomplish this using internal PHP functionality. I can write a function that will accomplish this easily myself, so hold answers like that.

Comment: Does preg_replace() count as internal PHP functionality?

Comment: From what you describe, I think it's equivalent to always leaving 1 number after the decimal dot (".")

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think theres a way to do that. A regex is probably your best solution:

```
$value = preg_replace('/(\.[0-9]+?)0*$/', '$1', $value);
```

Demo:

```
php> $a = array('0.000', '0.0001', '0.0101', '9.000', '9.100', '9.120', '9.123');
php> foreach($a as $b) { echo $b . ' => ' . preg_replace('/(\.[0-9]+?)0*$/', '$1', $b)."\n"; }
0.000 => 0.0
0.0001 => 0.0001
0.0101 => 0.0101
9.000 => 9.0
9.100 => 9.1
9.120 => 9.12
9.123 => 9.123
```

Comment: This does not work as  "9.01" would become "91". Needs some grouping!

Comment: You put me on the right track, although your answer isn't valid PHP (the order of your parameters is wrong). The proper way to do this, using preg_replace is preg_replace('/(?<!\.)0*$/', '', $value). So thanks for pushing me in the right direction. I'll award you the answer for helping me find the answer.

Comment: I think you need `preg_replace($value'/\.?0*$/','')` to handle things like 123.4500

Comment: @James The $ sign means end of string.  The pattern will not match ".0" in the middle of "9.01".

Comment: Joel true but "9.000" becomes "9" and "9.100" will stay "9.100".

Comment: Mixed up the argument order. now it works. Btw, if none of you got a warning you should change your PHP config.

Comment: Sorry but -1, just because it still fails (see @JamesAnderson comment).

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Still fails for `9.000` (should be `9.0`). This (http://stackoverflow.com/a/5429996/89771) handles it correctly.

Answer (score 8):

If you want a built-in solution and you're using a PHP version later than 4.2 you could try [`floatval()`](http://www.php.net/floatval):

```
echo floatval(9.200);
```

prints

```
9.2
```

but

```
echo floatval(9.123);
```

prints

```
9.123
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 7):

try something like this

```
$number = 2.00;
echo floor_dec($number,$deg);

    function floor_dec($number, $deg = null)
    {
        if ($deg == null)
            return $number * 1000 / 1000;
        else
            return $number * pow(10, $deg) / pow(10, $deg);
    }
```

will display "2"

Answer (score 5):

Shouldn't it be?:

```
$value = preg_replace('~0*$~', '', $value);
```

The PHP preg_replace syntax is

```
mixed preg_replace ( mixed $pattern , mixed $replacement , mixed $subject [, int $limit = -1 [, int &$count ]] )
```

Comment: +1, this is the only solution that does what the OP asked for.

Comment: @Thibault -- Your write  '~([.][0-9])0*$~' was too complex see edit!

Answer (score 2):

A trailing zero *is* significant:

- A value of 9.0 implies, that the real value is more than 8.9 and less than 9.1
- A value of 9.00000 implies, that the real value is more than 8.99999 and less than 9.00001

Therefore, your requirement is quite unusual. That's the reason why no function exists to do what you want.

Comment: This is more for display purposes than scientific accuracy. I know that's what significance means, which is why I put "non-zero" in parentheses. I suppose I could've worded my question better.

Comment: The rules for significant digits is also only for display purposes. During calculation, the highest possible accuracy is used. Only when the final result should be displayed, it is rounded to an adequate accuracy (so as not to imply an accuracy that the input never had).

Comment: I would have thought 9 is more than 8.9 and less than 9.1 too (juste like 9.0, with or without trailing 0)... what am I missing here?

Comment: @fpierrat The actual value is most likely an irrational number that cannot be displayed. Instead of displaying the actual value, a rational number is displayed that is close to the real value. This is called /rounding/. To let the reader know at which decimal place rounding occurred, trailing zeroes are displayed even if their omission would not alter the values of the displayed number.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
    $numbers = array(
        "9.000",
        "9.100",
        "9.120",
        "9.123"
    );
    foreach($numbers as $number) {
        echo sprintf(
            "%s -> %s\n",
            $number,
            (float) $number == (int) $number ? number_format($number, 1) : (float) $number
        );
    }
?>
```

Output:

```
9.000 -> 9.0
9.100 -> 9.1
9.120 -> 9.12
9.123 -> 9.123
```

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box that isn't possible because you have two different ways of treating the fragment of your floats. You'll first have to determine how many non-zero numbers there are in your fragment and then act accordingly with sprintf.

```
<?php

$numbers = array(
    '9.000',
    '9.100',
    '9.120',
    '9.123',
);

foreach ($numbers as $number) {

    $decimals = strlen(str_replace('0','', array_pop(explode('.', $number))));
    $decimals = $decimals ?: 1;
    echo $number . " => " . sprintf("%.{$decimals}f", $number);

    echo "<br/>";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
preg_replace(/\\.$/,'.0',rtrim($value,'0'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the number is encoded as or cast to a string, here's a general purpose approach:

```
$value = is_numeric($value) ? strval($value + 0) : $value;
```

Answer (score -1):

My solution is to let php handle it as a number (is *1) and then treat it as a string (my example I was using percentages stored as a decimal with 2 decimal places):

```
printf('%s%% off', $value*1);
```

This outputs:

```
0.00  => 0% off
0.01  => 0.01% off
20.00 => 20% off
20.50 => 20.5% off
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question asked

Answer (score -2):

> rtrim($value, "0") almost works. The problem with rtrim is that it leaves 9.000 as 9.

So just rtrim($value, "0.") and you're done.

Comment: -1, then `9.000` and `90.000` would become `9` and not `9.0` or `90.0`.

Comment: what about rtrim(rtrim($value,"0"), ".")