# Dynamic decimal places

Tags: php, decimal

I was using the function number_format() to manage my decimal places, but I'm not getting the result I want.
I wish to have up to 6 decimal places, but i don't want every number to display them. For example if my output is 27.54, number_format is gonna give me 27.540000. Is there function or a way to ignore those extra zeros and only display the significant decimals??
Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at this (possible duplicated): http://stackoverflow.com/a/5429945/722135

Comment: rtrim doesn't work for me, since it erases the zeros of my integers... my 25000 turns 25...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `(float)` to cast the value back to a float (which will remove the trailing 0's):

```
$val = number_format(11.11, 6);
echo (float)$val;
```

Comment: I dont know why, but if I use number_format it erases the zeros in my integers. the $val = (float) $val; doesn't let me limit the decimals, but works great removing the insignificant zeros!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

```
$r = 27.54;
 echo (float) number_format($r,6);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct, you want up to 6 decimals, but no more and if its less that 6 decimal places to ignore any zeros. If so, just get the `floatval` of the formated string:

```
$number = floatval(number_format($number,6))
```

Comment: this works great!! but only works when I'm dividing...when I'm multiplying I get 1.48 * 1000 = 1 ....