# PHP: format any float as a decimal expansion

Tags: php, floating-point, floating-point-conversion

I'd like to create a function `formatFloat()` which takes any float and formats it as a decimal expansion string.  For example:

```
formatFloat(1.0E+25);  // "10,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000"
formatFloat(1.0E+24);  // "1,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000"

formatFloat(1.000001);      // "1.000001"
formatFloat(1.000001E-10);  // "0.0000000001000001"
formatFloat(1.000001E-11);  // "0.00000000001000001"
```

## Initial ideas

Simply [casting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting) the float to a string won't work, because for floats larger than about `1.0E+14`, or smaller than about `1.0E-4`, PHP renders them in [scientific notation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ScientificNotation.html) instead of [decimal expansion](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DecimalExpansion.html).

[`number_format()`](http://www.php.net/number_format) is the obvious PHP function to try.  However, this problem occurs for large floats:

```
number_format(1.0E+25);  // "10,000,000,000,000,000,905,969,664"
number_format(1.0E+24);  // "999,999,999,999,999,983,222,784"
```

For small floats, the difficulty is choosing how many decimal digits to ask for.  One idea is to ask for a large number of decimal digits, and then [`rtrim()`](http://www.php.net/rtrim) the excess `0`s.  However, this idea is flawed because the decimal expansion often doesn't end with `0`s:

```
number_format(1.000001,     30);  // "1.000000999999999917733362053696"
number_format(1.000001E-10, 30);  // "0.000000000100000099999999996746"
number_format(1.000001E-11, 30);  // "0.000000000010000010000000000321"
```

The problem is that a floating point number has [limited precision](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php), and is usually unable to store the exact value of the literal (eg: `1.0E+25`).  Instead, it stores the closest possible value which *can* be represented.  `number_format()` is revealing these "closest approximations".

## Timo Frenay's solution

I discovered [this comment](http://www.php.net/sprintf#103755) buried deep in the [`sprintf()`](http://www.php.net/sprintf) page, surprisingly with no upvotes:

> Here is how to print a floating point number with 16 significant digits regardless of magnitude:

```
$result = sprintf(sprintf('%%.%dF', max(15 - floor(log10($value)), 0)), $value);
```

The key part is the use of [`log10()`](http://www.php.net/log10) to determine the [order of magnitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_magnitude) of the float, to then calculate the number of decimal digits required.

There are a few bugs which need fixing:

- The code doesn't work for negative floats.
- The code doesn't work for extremely small floats (eg: `1.0E-100`). PHP reports this notice: "`sprintf()`: Requested precision of 116 digits was truncated to PHP maximum of 53 digits"
- If `$value` is `0.0`, then `log10($value)` is `-INF`.
- Since the precision of a [PHP float](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) is "roughly 14 decimal digits", I think 14 significant digits should be displayed instead of 16.

## My best attempt

This is the best solution I've come up with.  It's based on Timo Frenay's solution, fixes the bugs, and uses [ThiefMaster's regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5429945/1851186) for trimming excess `0`s:

```
function formatFloat($value)
{
    if ($value == 0.0)  return '0.0';

    $decimalDigits = max(
        13 - floor(log10(abs($value))),
        0
    );

    $formatted = number_format($value, $decimalDigits);

    // Trim excess 0's
    $formatted = preg_replace('/(\.[0-9]+?)0*$/', '$1', $formatted);

    return $formatted;
}
```

[Here's an Ideone demo](http://ideone.com/TK4djd) with 200 random floats.  The code seems to work correctly for all floats smaller than about `1.0E+15`.

It's interesting to see that `number_format()` works correctly for even extremely small floats:

```
formatFloat(1.000001E-250);  // "0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000001"
```

## The question

My best attempt at `formatFloat()` still suffers from this problem:

```
formatFloat(1.0E+25);  // "10,000,000,000,000,000,905,969,664"
formatFloat(1.0E+24);  // "999,999,999,999,999,983,222,784"
```

Is there an elegant way to improve the code to solve this problem?

Comment: what you are looking for, is something like bcmath ; I myself wrote a decimal_number interface for php ; 15 years ago ; still have the code but I don't know if it is still accurate... ; going thru log10 is only making you looping-back to your first issue. Best.

Answer (score 2):

This piece of code [seems to do the job too](http://ideone.com/zhSxrm). I don't think I managed to make it any more elegant than yours, but I spent so much time on it that I can't just throw it away :)

```
function formatFloat(
    $value,
    $noOfDigits = 14,
    $separator = ',',
    $decimal = '.'
) {

    $exponent = floor(log10(abs($value)));
    $magnitude = pow(10, $exponent);

    // extract the significant digits
    $mantissa = (string)abs(round(($value /  pow(10, $exponent - $noOfDigits + 1))));
    $formattedNum = '';

    if ($exponent >= 0) { // <=> if ($value >= 1)

        // just for pre-formatting
        $formattedNum = number_format($value, $noOfDigits - 1, $decimal, $separator);

        // then report digits from $mantissa into $formattedNum
        $formattedLen = strlen($formattedNum);
        $mantissaLen = strlen($mantissa);
        for ($fnPos = 0, $mPos = 0; $fnPos <  $formattedLen; $fnPos++, $mPos++) {

            // skip non-digit
            while($formattedNum[$fnPos] === $separator || $formattedNum[$fnPos] === $decimal || $formattedNum[$fnPos] === '-') {
                $fnPos++;
            }
            $formattedNum[$fnPos] = $mPos < $mantissaLen ? $mantissa[$mPos] : '0';

        }

    } else { // <=> if ($value < 1)

        // prepend minus sign if necessary
        if ($value < 0) {
            $formattedNum = '-';
        }
        $formattedNum .= '0' . $decimal . str_repeat('0', abs($exponent) - 1) . $mantissa;

    }

    // strip trailing decimal zeroes
    $formattedNum = preg_replace('/\.?0*$/', '', $formattedNum);

    return $formattedNum;

}
```

Comment: Yes I realise that a PHP float can't represent `1.0E+25` precisely. So what's needed is an algorithm which takes the imprecise float representation of `1.0E+25`, and converts it to a string representation rounded to 14 significant digits. It _is_ possible to create a function which does this and only accepts a native PHP float as the input parameter (as [my inelegant answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22390446/1851186) demonstrates).

Comment: @TachyonVortex ... and I realise I didn't understand your question in the first place. Now I understand from your code. I tried very hard to find a better way to do it, but this is all I could put together (see edit).

Comment: Many thanks for your code, and for all the time and effort that you put into it - it's much appreciated! I'm interested to see your approach, using `number_format()` to do the pre-formatting, and then either copying digits from the mantissa, or copying `0`s if there are no mantissa digits left.

Comment: Script on linked page has some problems: WARNING Division by zero on line number 83

WARNING str_repeat() expects parameter 2 to be integer, float given on line number 110
0 --> 0.0 --> 0.NAN 
WARNING Division by zero on line number 83

WARNING str_repeat() expects parameter 2 to be integer, float given on line number 110
0 --> 0.0 --> 0.NAN 
WARNING Division by zero on line number 83

WARNING str_repeat() expects parameter 2 to be integer, float given on line number 110

Comment: I don't have so much time to edit and test that is it corrected perfectly. If you have a solved version, i will thank you for your share.

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to create this (rather inelegant) solution.

If the float is smaller than `1.0E+14`, then it uses my "best attempt" code from my question. Otherwise, it rounds the integer part to 14 significant digits.

[Here's an Ideone demo](http://ideone.com/v9rn3D) with 500 random floats, and the code seems to work correctly for all of them.

As I say, this is not a very elegant implementation, so I'm still very interested to know if someone can devise a better solution.

```
function formatFloat($value)
{
    $phpPrecision = 14;

    if ($value == 0.0)  return '0.0';

    if (log10(abs($value)) < $phpPrecision) {

        $decimalDigits = max(
            ($phpPrecision - 1) - floor(log10(abs($value))),
            0
        );

        $formatted = number_format($value, $decimalDigits);

        // Trim excess 0's
        $formatted = preg_replace('/(\.[0-9]+?)0*$/', '$1', $formatted);

        return $formatted;

    }

    $formattedWithoutCommas = number_format($value, 0, '.', '');

    $sign = (strpos($formattedWithoutCommas, '-') === 0) ? '-' : '';

    // Extract the unsigned integer part of the number
    preg_match('/^-?(\d+)(\.\d+)?$/', $formattedWithoutCommas, $components);
    $integerPart = $components[1];

    // Split into significant and insignificant digits
    $significantDigits   = substr($integerPart, 0, $phpPrecision);
    $insignificantDigits = substr($integerPart, $phpPrecision);

    // Round the significant digits (using the insignificant digits)
    $fractionForRounding = (float) ('0.' . $insignificantDigits);
    $rounding            = (int) round($fractionForRounding);  // Either 0 or 1
    $rounded             = $significantDigits + $rounding;

    // Pad on the right with zeros
    $formattingString = '%0-' . strlen($integerPart) . 's';
    $formatted        = sprintf($formattingString, $rounded);

    // Insert a comma between every group of thousands
    $formattedWithCommas = strrev(
        rtrim(
            chunk_split(
                strrev($formatted), 3, ','
            ),
            ','
        )
    );

    return $sign . $formattedWithCommas;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
number_format($result, 14, '.', '');
```

Comment: Its often better to have a brief explanation than to have code only answers.

Comment: @IdeaHat: Very true. Scott: your answer doesn't seem to solve the problem in my original question. Please can you add an explanation.