# How to disable scientific notation for values like 0.000005 in PHP (json_encode)?

Tags: php, json, floating-point, scientific-notation

I'm trying to integrate with some Partner API.

They only accept json with float type for amount.

Example:

- OK

  - `{"amount":0.0000005}`
- Error

  - `{"amount":"0.0000005"}`
  - `{"amount":5.0E-7}`

If the value greater or equal 1, then it's OK scenario always. But in my case I have values > 0, and < 1.

Code Example:

```php
$arr = ['amount' => 0.0000005];
$str = json_encode($arr);

echo $str;
```

Output:

```
{"amount":5.0e-7}
```

I want the output to look like this:

```
{"amount":0.0000005}
```

Is it possible in php? May be some hacks & tricks?

Comment: As a point of reference, it seems that the scientific notation is a valid "number" according to [the IETF's JSON specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259#section-6), as well as [Crockford's original definition](https://www.json.org); so, it's not a PHP bug, and not a different data type as such. That doesn't really help you if the system on the other hand doesn't comply with those specs, and isn't someone you have influence over, though.

Comment: @Uwe NO. It's different situations. I specifically indicated for which values I get an error!

Comment: Sorry @A1t - my mistake. I was at decode and not encode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest I can think of is to traverse through the data, recursively substituting small numbers with a placeholder; then, after JSON encoding, replace the placeholders in the final JSON string with the number formatted how you want it.

The surprisingly difficult part is formatting the float itself; I found [this existing question about how to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22274437/157957) with some working but not very elegant implementations. For brevity, I've left that part as a TODO below.

```
class JsonMangler
{
    private const THRESHOLD = 0.0001;
    private const PLACEHOLDER = '__PLACEHOLDER__';

    private array $mangledData = [];
    private array $substitutions = [];
    private int $placeholderIncrement = 0;

    public function __construct(array $realData) {
        // Start the recursive function
        $this->mangledData = $this->mangle($realData);
    }

    private function mangle(array $realData): array {
        $mangledData = [];

        foreach ( $realData as $key => $realValue ) {
            if ( is_float($realValue) && $realValue < self::THRESHOLD) {
                // Substitute small floats with a placeholder
                $substituteValue = self::PLACEHOLDER . ($this->placeholderIncrement++);
                $mangledData[$key] = $substituteValue;
                // Placeholder will appear in quotes in the JSON, which we want to replace away
                $this->substitutions["\"$substituteValue\""] = $this->formatFloat($realValue);
            }
            elseif ( is_array($realValue) ) {
                // Recurse through the data
                $mangledData[$key] = $this->mangle($realValue);
            }
            else {
                // Retain everything else
                $mangledData[$key] = $realValue;
            }
        }

        return $mangledData;
    }

    /**
     * Format a float into a string without any exponential notation
     */
    private function formatFloat(float $value): string
    {
        // This is surprisingly hard to do; see https://stackoverflow.com/q/22274437/157957
        return 'TODO';
    }

    public function getJson(int $jsonEncodeFlags = 0): string
    {
        $mangledJson = json_encode($this->mangledData, $jsonEncodeFlags);
        return str_replace(array_keys($this->substitutions), array_values($this->substitutions), $mangledJson);
    }
}
```

Using [this implementation for `formatFloat`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22390446/157957), the following test:

```
$example = [
    'amount' => 1.5,
    'small_amount' => 0.0001,
    'tiny_amount' => 0.0000005,
    'subobject' => [
        'sub_value' => 42.5,
        'tiny_sub_value' => 0.0000425,
        'array' => [
            1.23,
            0.0000123
        ]
    ]
];
echo (new JsonMangler($example))->getJson(JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Results in the following output:

```json
{
    "amount": 1.5,
    "small_amount": 0.0001,
    "tiny_amount": 0.0000005,
    "subobject": {
        "sub_value": 42.5,
        "tiny_sub_value": 0.0000425,
        "array": [
            1.23,
            0.0000123
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to keep it the long way is to convert it to a string instead. **But then it is not a number anymore!**

```
$arr = ['amount' => number_format(0.0000005, 7)];
$str = json_encode($arr);
```

giving

```
{"amount":"0.0000005"}
```

Javascript itself would use the scientific notation:

```
j = {"amount":"0.0000005"};
parseFloat(j.amount);
5e-7
```

A hack would be to remove the quotes.

```
$quoteless = preg_replace('/:"(\d+.\d+)"/', ':$1', $str);
echo $quoteless;
```

will give

```
{"amount":0.0000005}
```